# How can i set new domains to respond to my server

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, cname-record, automation, ns-record

I would like to create a page for new clients in my hosting.

When someone register a domain, sometimes that person don't have a dns, or the hosting didn't created the account.

So the page will not respond.

Is there any way to set in my primary domain DNS to respond to all domains pointing to me, to a specific new page like home/resseler/public_html/soon.html  ?

Like a CNAME
myserver.com/soon.html  CNAME  ~~all domains pointing to my ns1 and ns2.

A normal default page for news domains pointed to my server without account creation.

Comment: I suggest you spend some time learning how DNS and Name Based Virtual Hosting works.

Comment: Have you ever tried to send a letter or email to someone who doesn't have an address? Same thing with something that has no DNS entry.

Comment: So, automatic catchall dns park service, without creating a virtual host that actually respond for a domain, isn't possible? Am i right?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can not enter a URL inside a DNS entry.

What you're looking for is a catch-all webserver. The trick here is to reserve a IP-address for parked domains, and assign that IP address to a specific virtual host with your "Coming soon" page.

I'm not giving out more details, as this is something that sysadmins should be able to figure out on their own.

Comment: Sure, thanks! That's what i was looking for! i will try to learn some more about dns and manage webservers.

Would you recommend some book or site to learn linux server creation and management?

Comment: From what i'v been reading there is a solution with a script that reads the apache error log for domains not responding and create a virtual host and bing configuration?

Comment: No, like I said, you create a virtual host that binds a IP. Every request to that IP will go to that virtual host, no matter what kind of domain it is - as long as it points to that IP.